# Razberry z wave plus devices vs z wave devices

Tags: raspberry-pi2, z-wave

Wave de Sigma Designs 5202(razberry for my raspberry pi 2 b 2014) so i would like to know if i can use devices with z wave plus and z wave.
Do you know if razberry can control z wave devices also ?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes, z wave is a protocol and the new z wave plus is a protocol that use the lastone , so if you was using 2000 devices now you are going to use more devices 4000 or more etc ,... so theres not problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, razpberry board also integrated z-wave controller. You can connect any z-wave components to any of z-wave controller. It is must behaviour of z-wave.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Z-Wave Plus is completely backwards compatable with standard Z-Wave. Anything that works with Z-Wave Plus will also work with Z-Wave, and anything that works with Z-Wave will work with Z-Wave Plus although it may not support all the added features of Z-Wave Plus.

[Here are some of the added features of Z-Wave Plus.](http://www.vesternet.com/what-is-z-wave-plus)